# Math assistance with my Grid: nth-child(an+b)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to make a grid that is not dependent on a preset number of columns. I created a small sample to show the situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Grid in HTML5 and CSS3</title>
<style>

* {margin:0;padding:0;}
.row {display:block;position:relative;clear:both;}
.row>* {display:block;position:relative;clear:both;float:left;clear:none;width:100%;}
.row>*:empty {width:0px;}

/* one column in the row */
.row>:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(1) {width:100%;} 

/* two columns in the row */
.row>:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(1) {width:50%;} 
.row>:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(2) {width:50%;} 

/* three columns in the row */
.row>:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(1) {width:33.33%;} 
.row>:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2) {width:33.33%;}
.row>:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(3) {width:33.34%;} 
.row>:empty:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(1)+:not(:empty) {width:66.66%;} 
.row>:empty:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2)+:not(:empty) {width:66.67%;}

article {margin:.5em;border:1px solid green;border-radius:.3em;padding:.5em; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<section class="row">
<div>
<article>
<p>This row has only one child.</p>
</article>
</div>
</section>

<section class="row">
<div>
<article>
<p>This row has two children</p>
</article>
</div>
<div>
<article>
<p>This is the second child</p>
</article>
</div>
</section>

<section class="row">
<div>
<article>
<p>
This row has three children
</p>
</article>
</div>
<div>
<article>
<p>So this is col 2 of 3</p>
</article>
</div>
<div>
<article>
<p>And this is col 3 of 3.</p>
</article>
</div>
</section>

<section class="row">
<div></div>
<div>
<article>
<p>The first child of this row is empty so spanned with the second</p>
</article>
</div>
<div>
<article>
<p>This is the second column</p>
</article>
</div>
</section>

<section class="row">
<div>
<article>
<p>This is the first column</p>
</article>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
<article>
<p>The second and third column are spanned</p>
</article>
</div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I put a larger sample - describing the problems in more detail - on jsfiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/jordenvanforeest/MDv32/

My problem now is that if you want this grid to accomodate for more than 3 columns, the CSS-size gets big exponentially. So I am looking for an other solution. I tried to do something like

```
.row>:nth-last-child(an+b):nth-child(cn+d) {}
```

but my calculus skills are a bit rusty and I cannot get it to work properly.
Help would be much appreciated.

**update**

[thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot) provided an answer that made the CSS much smaller. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jordenvanforeest/rRXq2/) is the improved version suggested by him.

Any other suggestions are still welcome. My 12 collumn Grid still needs 30K for the spanning.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Only downside is the current implementation requires empty divs, how would you see this being used in production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something similar with `display: table` combined [with `table-layout: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-table-layout).

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-table (but the limiting factor here is [`:not()` and `:empty`](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3))

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/MDv32/3/

As you can see, it looks virtually identical. With some ingenuity, you should be able to replicate most of the functionality in your demo with the technique used in mine. I commented out the HTML in my demo where I stopped.

**CSS:**

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.row > * {
    display: table-cell;
}
.row > :empty {
    display: none;
}
/* for example: */
.row > :empty + :not(:empty) + :last-child:not(:empty) {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!
It seems to exactly what I want. Why are saying that it only does 90%?
Am I missing someting?

Comment: It might not behave identically when you have nested rows. It's probably close enough though, so I've changed that sentence.